# Перевод темы WordPress - .mo файл грузится, но перевод не отображается

Tags: wordpress, wpml

Перепробовал уже все что можно, но никак не могу заставить работать перевод.

.po файл был сгенерирован плагином WPML, после чего через poedit превратил его в .mo файл.
На данном этапе, у меня такие "симптомы":

- ru_RU.po файл экспортируется, однако при повторном импорте русский язык не определяется. Есть только дополнительное безымянное поле, а перевод на Русский предлагается ручками
- .mo файл же подключается.

load_theme_textdomain возвращает true, локаль тоже подхватывается. Файл тоже читабельный, проверял и через is_readable() , и уже на винде пробовал, не работает.

Сейчас попробую через другой плагин\софт сделать новый .po файл и повторить цикл.

UPD: решил проблему, воспользовавшись вот этим мануалом:
https://localise.biz/help/wordpress/loading-translations#debug

А именно:

```
function debug_load_textdomain( $domain , $mofile  ){
    echo "Trying ",$domain," at ",$mofile,"<br />\n";
}
add_action('load_textdomain','debug_load_textdomain');
```

В окне браузера я увидел что файлы перевода ищутся не в папке темы, а в /wp-content/languages.

после удаления файлов перводов моей темы из этой папки, вордпресс начал искать перевод уже в папке с темой, там где надо.

Если честно, я не совсем понял  **что вообще случилось**, но знаю что убил я на это часов эдак 6. Если можно, пожалуйста, обьясните пожалуйста почему так получилось?

Comment: История увлекательная, но совершенно непонятная :)

Comment: @KAGGDesign если бы я на тот момент хотя бы понимал в чем проблема)
Все сделано как по книжке, именования, домен... а где перевод?:)))
А нима